# Facebook registration plugin "Invalid client_id" error when logging out

Tags: plugins, facebook, registration

I'm using the fb registration plugin on my site, but i recently started to notice an issue. when users click the "X" and then log out of facebook, i get an error that says "Invalid 'client_id'". I checked [this post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4845721/facebook-apis-fbregistration-returning-invalid-client-id-when-not-connected), but it doesn't apply to me because my app is not in sandbox mode. Here is a before and after image of the scenario:

[image]

After logging out the user sees:

[image]

Comment: Is the app ID you initialised the plugin with valid?

Comment: Did you came up with a solution? I've run into the same problem.

Comment: This needs a fix, I've go this also.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exactly same issue, tried many other different sugestions on web none of them worked.

I only got the issue resolved when I created a new app and used a new ID.